# Handling State changes jQuery and History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I need some insight into working with History.js and jQuery.

I have it set up and working (just not quite as you'd expect).

What I have is as follows:

```
$(function() {

 var History = window.History;
 if ( !History.enabled ) {
      return false;
 }

// Capture all the links to push their url to the history stack and trigger the StateChange Event
$('.ajax-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = this.href; //Tells us which page to load
    var id = $(this).data('passid'); //Pass ID -- the ID in which to save in our state object
      e.preventDefault();
        console.log('url: '+url+'    id:'+id);

      History.pushState({ 'passid' : id }, $(this).text(), url);
});

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    console.log('state changed');
    var State = History.getState(),
        id = State.data.editid; //the ID passed, if available

    $.get(State.url, 
        { id: State.data.passid }, 
        function(response) {

        $('#subContent').fadeOut(200, function(){ 
            var newContent = $(response).find('#subContent').html();
            $('#subContent').html(newContent);

            var scripts = $('script');
            scripts.each(function(i) {
             jQuery.globalEval($(this).text());
        });


            $('#subContent').fadeIn(200);
         });
    });
});
}); //end dom ready
```

It works as you'd expect as far as changing the url, passing the ID, changing the content. My question is this: 
If I press back/forward on my browser a couple times the subContent section will basically fadeIn/fadeOut multiple times.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

===================================================

Edit: The problem was in my calling all of my `<script>` and Eval them on each statechange. By adding a class="no-reload" to the history controlling script tag I was able to do:

```
var scripts = $('script').not('.no-reload');
```

This got rid of the problem and it now works as intended. Figure I will leave this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue as I did.

Comment: We don't do "(Solved) " in the titles here on SO. If you were able to answer your own question you can add an answer and mark it as accepted, or you can just delete the question.

Comment: Ok, I tried to just edit it and add in an answer, but I didn't know I was supposed to reply to my own topic with an answer. Is there no way to do that in the original post?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my calling of all of my `<script>` and Eval them on each statechange. By adding a class="no-reload" to the history controlling script tag I was able to do:

```
var scripts = $('script').not('.no-reload');
```

This got rid of the problem and it now works as intended. Figure I will leave this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue as I did.